# Error on setting up my own IP through http.createServer.listen()

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, http, server

I use aws cloud9 as the backend and want to access an index.html through my own public IP. However, there is an error and cannot be run successfully. What is the problem here?

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer( function (request, response) {
  var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  console.log("Trying to find '" + pathname.substr(1) + "'...");

  fs.readFile(pathname.substr(1), function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      response.write("ERROR: Cannot find '" + pathname.substr(1) + "'.");
      console.log("ERROR: Cannot find '" + pathname.substr(1) + "'.");
    } else {
      console.log("Found '" + pathname.substr(1) + "'.");
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      response.write(data.toString());
    }
    response.end();
  });
}).listen(8080, '54.25x.xxx.xxx'); // Or 8081 or 8082 instead of 8080. Or '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'.
```

The code can be run and create a server if I type .listen(8080, 'localhost')
However, if I change it to IPv4 Public IP, it cannot be run.

The error is the following:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:15454/*********


For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector

Debugger attached.
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 54.25*.***.***:8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1263:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1328:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1461:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1307:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am confused by your statement of "using aws cloud9 as the backend" (that's not what Cloud9 is meant for), but i will not be explaining concepts and stick to your immediate problem.

Supposing that you followed the [AWS documentation on the matter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-share) because you already know your public IP, there is two critical things not to forget:

1. per [Step 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-share-security-group), you must add a Security Group inbound rule to the Cloud9 environment EC2, for the app's listening port (say 8080) and public internet access (or just your own local machine public IP, as you wish). Contrary to Subnet NACL setting described in Step 3, which already allows all inbound traffic, EC2 Security Group (as predefined by Cloud9) only allows SSH.
2. **the confusing part and probably your main problem if you followed the doc otherwise** - i have no idea why AWS documentation wants you to [use EC2 public IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/app-preview.html#app-preview-share-change-port). The poor EC2 box does not even have an interface with that IP - therefore `EADDRNOTAVAIL`. Check yourself by typing `ifconfig` in the console. So two solutions here:

   1. use the IP that you see in `ifconfig` with `eth0`
   2. use `0.0.0.0` which means "listen on any available network address". That would listen also on adapters that you didn't mean (like Docker adapter which Cloud9 host is running in), which may be a problem for you, but more likely is not.

In any case, it's really just a temporary solution. You may lose the specific public IP at any time. If you want more persistent setup, attach an Elastic IP to the Cloud9 EC2 instance.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I use the 0.0.0.0 and then it works but in the AWS doc, it said " In your code, switch from using IP 127.0.0.1, localhost, or 0.0.0.0 to using the IP address or addresses you specified in the previous steps in this section. " I just follow this and change the ip from localhost to my owns

Comment: As you mentioned before, can I use Elastic IPs to deal with the problem of losing the specific public IP?

Comment: Yes exactly that is the confusing part of AWS that i mention in chapter No.2. It simply does not work as documented. Re Elastic IP - you absolutely can and i added it to my answer. Only don't forget to Release the EIP when you are finished with EC2/Cloud9. AWS charges per hour for an allocated but unreleased EIPs.